# Spotify API mosaic view

Tags: api, view, spotify, mosaic

I am trying to adjust the size of the album art thumbnails in the mosaic view. I can set the width and hieght of the space for the mosaic view using the code below but I don't know how to adjust the size of the actual images that are displayed:

```
var mosaic = new views.Image(playlist.image);
    mosaic.node.style.width = '312px';
    mosaic.node.style.height = '162px';
    mosaic.node.style.backgroundSize = 'cover';
    $('#mosaic').append(mosaic.node);
```

Can anyone help?

thanks in advance, 
James

Answer (score 0):

The mosaic view uses a background image generated with 4 covers taken from the playlist tracks. This image is a squared sprite with fixed dimensions of 300x300 pixels, and currently there is no way to set a different size for the generated background.

In order to prevent blurring, you could stick to 300x150 pixels for the style of the node, which will show 2 covers from the mosaic image. You could also increase the area to 300x300 so that the whole mosaic image with 4 covers is shown.